# GridSearchCV scikit-learn: TypeError LogisticRegression...does not implement a 'get_params' methods

Tags: python, typeerror, clone, logistic-regression, gridsearchcv

I want to optimize the hyperparameters of the logistic regression estimator using sklearn's GridSearchCV (see https://towardsdatascience.com/hyperparameter-tuning-c5619e7e6624), based on following code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test,indices_train,indices_test = train_test_split(features_all2, df_all['labels'], df_all.index, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)

penalty = ['l1', 'l2']
C = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]
class_weight = ['balanced']
solver = ['liblinear', 'saga']

param_grid = dict(penalty=penalty,
                  C=C,
                  class_weight=class_weight,
                  solver=solver)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=LogisticRegression,
                    param_grid=param_grid,
                    scoring='roc_auc',
                    verbose=1,
                    n_jobs=-1)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Best Score: ', grid_result.best_score_)
print('Best Params: ', grid_result.best_params_)
```

It works fine until `grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)` where I get the error **TypeError: Cannot clone object '' (type ): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.**

Although when doing `hasattr(LogisticRegression, 'get_params')` I get *True*.

I am stuck here. Anybody out there might has an idea how to handle this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: it should be `estimator= LogisticRegression()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `estimator= LogisticRegression()` instead of `estimator= LogisticRegression`

**example:**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
grid={"C":np.logspace(-3,3,7), "penalty":["l1","l2"]}# l1 lasso l2 ridge
logreg=LogisticRegression()
logreg_cv=GridSearchCV(logreg,grid,cv=10)
```